# Can I use Razer Comms' LoL Scouter on League of Legends Garena?

Tags: league-of-legends

Garena is the distributor for League of Legends in South East Asia, I am a razer fanatic and owner of many razer headsets. Today I tried to open my LoL ACC via Garena and open comms @ the same time, hoping that I would get a chance to use the scouter as I was in game when I opened comms. So does this really work on Garena LoL? Or does it only work on NA/EU etc. servers? If yes, how? Am looking for steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i'm afraid that it's not possible.

The reason for this is that Garena as a company don't want software competing with their own.

Garena has their own Voice Comm known as "TalkTalk", which you can find [here](http://www.garena.sg/talktalk/).

Letting people use other software makes them lose potential users.